# Como desmarcar um checkbox, quando fechar a div que mostra o que foi marcado.?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Depois que eu marco as opções do checkbox, clico em "ok" ele ele me trás as opções que marquei. dando a opção de excluí-la. Mas se eu excluo, o checkbox ainda continua marcado.

Comment: Poste o código já feito para facilitar a visualização e possíveis ajustes necessários.

Comment: Se você está usando JQuery, para desmarcar um checkbox, você pode setar o atributo "checked" como falso, assim: `$('#checkbox').prop('checked', false);`. Se estiver usando Javascript puro, use  `document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = false;`

Comment: Renato, no caso seria uma lista, se eu remover só 1 ele só deve desmarcar o checkbox relacionado à aquele que removi da lista, mantendo os demais.

Comment: Coloque o seu código na pergunta, para facilitar.